# How do I change the organizer of a meeting I have scheduled in my Outlook Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I have a meeting that I accepted from somebody else on my Outlook calendar, and because of a syncing issue, I need to be able to change the organizer in my calendar to myself, instead of the person who sent it to me, because the sync program won't recognize it otherwise.

How do you change the organizer of a meeting in Outlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever originates the meeting is the owner and Outlook 2010 does not support what you need to do. A possible workaround; you can delete the appointment from your calendar and recreate it on your own calendar in order to be the owner of the appointment. You don't have to send it to all the same people, just save it on your calendar.

*Note: You might want to let the organizer know what you are doing in case they receive a message that you deleted the meeting request.*

Answer (score 0):

The organizer is not whoever originates the meeting. It is the owner of the calendar the meeting is created on.
For instance, if I own a shared calendar named "Devices checked out" and someone creates a meeting on it I will always be the organizer because it is my calendar.

The situation you are referring to, the person created a meeting on their calendar and invited you to it, so they are the owner of their calendar and therefore are the organizer.
If you want to be the organizer, create the meeting on your calendar and invite the other people.